# Loading an image from CSS with webpack, relative path

Tags: webpack, sass, webpacker

I have a tree like

```
app
  images
  stylesheets
    style.scss
other-app
  style.scss
```

And

```
// in other-app/style.scss
@import "./../app/stylesheets/style.scss"


// in app/stylesheets/styles.scss
...
  background: url('./../images/some-image.png');
...
```

webpack fails to compile because it tries to resolve `other-app/../images/some-image.png`. I tried absolute path like /app/images/some-image.png`, it compiles but the resource can't be found at run time.

For info I'm using latest webpacker.

Comment: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/256 take a look at the answer at the bottom, maybe that will help you.

Comment: ended up using resolve, thanks for the link it helped